# superfluous parameters in call to ASMX service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

In ASP.NET, **WHY its possible** to call a function of a web service with more parameter than the function ask (the superfluous parameters are simply unused)?

---

I need to do a kind of reverse engineering.
I got a web service with the function myFunction(param A, param B)

and I have a web site calling the service with more parameter

```
MyService.MyFunction(A,B,C);
```

It's seems working but I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a "web service function". As far as the client is concerned, it's a set of descriptions in a WSDL document. From that description, client code is generated. That client code causes XML (SOAP) to be sent to the service.

It is possible for this to get out of sync. For instance, version 1 of the service may have had 3 parameters on the operation. A client was created for version 1, so it sends 3 parameters.

Version 2 of the service may remove one parameter. If the client is not updated, then it still will send 3 parameters. The service may choose to ignore the extra parameter.

Comment: it seems that he choose to ignore the extra parameter. So you said, thats how the service manage extra parameter?

Comment: Most likely, it simply doesn't deserialize the extra parameter.

Comment: BTW, just to make sure you know: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass a model with the parameters you need, for example, if you are expecting:

```
firstname, lastname, city
```

you can make your object as:

```
public class Person {
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}
```

and have your method receive a `Person` object like

```
public bool SavePerson(Person person) { ... }
```

later on, you can simply append more properties to the `Person` object.

So, that might actually be what's going on... let's image that you can pass `firstname` and `lastname`, but `city` is optional.

Comment: it seems I'm wrong made ​​me understand. I Want to know why a web service function accept been calling with more parameter than it's been declared?

Comment: I can add as much as I want, it's a simple POST/GET... so I'm able to pass `n` parameters... it just takes the one that it requires and ignores everything else... maybe you are passing something for logging for example... the call simple ignores. a Web Service, as the name says **web**, it's a simple POST/GET or even send JSON or XML values...